# Python logging calls showing on console even when redirecting stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, stdout, io-redirection

I'm on a Windows 7 machine with Python 3.6

I'm wondering why the following code prints the logger message to the console even though the logger (or rather its parent's handler) is configured to emit to stdout and stdout is redirected to `io.StringIO()`.

```
import sys
import logging
from io import StringIO

logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG, stream=sys.stdout)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = tmp = StringIO()
print('*** FIRST IN CODE : print')
logger.debug('*** SECOND IN CODE : logger')
sys.stdout = old_stdout
print(tmp.getvalue())
```

If you comment out the last line in this code (`print(tmp.getvalue())`) you'll see that `*** FIRST IN CODE : print` no longer shows up on the console while `*** SECOND IN CODE : logger` still does.

I've tried removing `stream=sys.stdout` from the `basicConfig()` call (in which case the `StreamHandler` that gets created will default to stderr) and redirected stderr instead but the result is the exact same as with stdout.

I've also looked at the `StreamHandler`'s code but that didn't explain anything either.

I've read that there are a few quirks with stdout/-err redirection on Windows. Is that what's happening here or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `stream=sys.stdout` to configure the logger, the logger gets a reference to the original `sys.stdout` value, just like `old_stdout` does in the line afterward.

When you change `sys.stdout`, you don't expect the value of `old_stdout` to change, right? So why should the value of `logger.stream` (or whatever it's really named) change?

The logger doesn't notice that you've since changed the value of the variable you used to assign the `stream` parameter. To do that, it would need to compare the received `stream` parameter to all possible sources, including `sys.stdout`, and then check that source later to see whether it still matches the `stream` parameter. That's way too much work, and doesn't follow general expectations of assigning values to variables or parameters.

If you want to redirect output, do so *before* telling other parts of your program (such as your logger) where to send their output.

For all the logger knows, you *intended* to keep logging going to the console while other output got sent elsewhere.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and I feel a little stupid now because that's probably something I should've realized. Thank you very much.